# How can I select 2 tables in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, join, select

I have 2 tables, the first one is called "test1" :

```
COL1
Blabla
foo
lib
```

The second one is "test2" :

```
COL2 
test
gg 
op
```

I want to use a select statement (with Oracle) for both tables (with col1=col2) and ordering the table by col1(or col2).

I want to get

```
COL1
Blabla
foo
lib
test
gg 
op
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need to show duplicates? Depending on that you should union these two tables

Answer (score 0):

Unless i misunderstand this is quite basic sql stuff

`select * from test1 t1 inner join test2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.col2 order by col1`

will give you all columns in test1 and test2 that satisfies the condition col1=col2 and then ordering them by col1

if you need a specific output, then specify the columns you need, e.g.

```
select t1.Col1, t1.BlaBla, t1.foo, t1.Lib, t2.test, t2.gg, t2.op from test1 t1 inner join test2 t2 on t1.col1=t2.col2 order by col1
```

I assume your example includes your data and not column names, so modify the sql statement to match your database

consider visiting the site http://www.sql-join.com/ to get more familiar with joins

Answer (score 0):

`Union`, right?

```
SQL> select col1 from test1
  2  union
  3  select col2 from test2
  4  order by 1;

COL1
------
blabla
foo
gg
lib
op
test

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Though, sort isn't like in your desired output. Unless there's a column you can use to order data by, hm, you're pretty much out of luck.